# Handling Callbacks From Dynamically Attached Elements in Ember

Tags: templates, view, callback, ember.js

I am using the [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/) library with ember. It dynamically creates a view when a button is clicked. In such a situation, what is the correct way to deal with callbacks from this view. Should I create callback functions on my View and hook them up to the dynamically created view using the `didInsertElement` hook?  The view element is not declared in a template and therefore I can't hook it up using an action.

Here's an example of what I've got at the moment. It's working fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way:

```
App.NewsItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'cms/news_item',
  tagName: 'li',

  onDateSave: function(e, params) {
      self.get('content').set('date', params['newValue']);
  },

  didInsertElement: function() {

    var elementID = this.get('elementId');

    var editDate = $("#" + elementID + " .edit-date");

    editDate.editable({
      autotext: 'never',
      display: false,
      send: 'never'
    });

    var self = this;

    editDate.on('save', function(e, params) {
      self.onDateSave(e, params);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It might be easiest to just implement the logic yourself with `Ember.View`. You'll probably need a lot of customization anyway, and it's easier than it looks :)

Comment: I agree with @JakubArnold. That said, yes the typical approach to integrating external libraries (such as jQueryUI) is to wrap it in an Ember.View-using observers to handle 'incoming' changes and tying into the library's own hooks to pick up state changes in the other direction-to serve as the interface.

Comment: @JakubArnold I'd love to implement it myself, but unfortunately got to lean the library due to time constraints.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey Can you clarify exactly what you mean 'tying into the library's own hooks to pick up state changes in the other direction-to serve as the interface.' Would you setup callbacks in `didInsertElement`, or approach it differently?

Comment: Yes, you'd set up your callbacks in `didInsertElement`. By `tying into hooks` I mean whatever mechanism the library has for notifying other code of changes. jQueryUI for instance calls them `events`, and your wrapping view would be in charge of adding one of its member methods as an observer for, for instance, the `selected` action on a jQueryUI drop-down control, so that you can reflect in your custom Ember View the current state of the control you're wrapping so that other ember objects can use bindings and observers without knowing about the wrapping behaviour..